plotly grouped barplot: how to specify quartiles but showoutliers
I am creating a grouped boxplot using plotly. I have to specify the quanitles because I have a specific way of calculating them. I also want to add the outliers to the plot as with standard behavior for a boxplot where plotly calculates the quantiles internally. I am currently trying to add them as a separate trace, but they end up in the middle of the grouped boxes. Maybe there is a way of adding them along with the plotly call that adds the grouped boxes, but if there is I cant't see it. How can I make it so that the outliers line up with the boxes? Reprex below.

set.seed(123) # Set seed for reproducibility

# Create the site_name column with 5 different site names, each with 20 rows
site_name <- rep(paste0("site_", 1:5), each = 40)

# Create the site_type column with 10 'A's and 10 'B's for each site
site_type <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 20, times = 5)

# Create the value column with random numbers
value <- runif(100, min = 0, max = 200) # Random numbers between 0 and 100

# Combine into a data frame
df <- data.frame(site_name, site_type, value)

# Display the first few rows of the dataset
head(df, 20)

# Group by site_name and site_type, then calculate summary statistics
stats_df <- df %>%
  group_by(site_name, site_type) %>%
  summarise(
    lower_fence = quantile(value, probs = c(0.05), type = 5, na.rm = TRUE),
    q1 = quantile(value, probs = c(0.25), type = 5, na.rm = TRUE),
    median = quantile(value, probs = c(0.5), type = 5, na.rm = TRUE),
    mean = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE),
    q3 = quantile(value, probs = c(0.75), type = 5, na.rm = TRUE),
    upper_fence = quantile(value, probs = c(0.95), type = 5, na.rm = TRUE),
    sd = sd(value, na.rm = TRUE),
    .groups = 'drop'
  )

# Create the grouped bar plot
fig <- plot_ly(
  data = stats_df,
  x = ~factor(site_name),
  color = ~factor(site_type),
  colors = c("blue","red"),
  type = "box",
  source = "boxes",
  lowerfence = ~lower_fence,
  q1 = ~q1,
  median = ~median,
  q3 = ~q3,
  upperfence = ~upper_fence,
  showlegend = show_legend
) %>% 
  layout(boxmode = "group")

# Extract outliers
filtered_df<- df %>%
  left_join(stats_df, by = c("site_name", "site_type")) %>%
  filter(value < lower_fence | value > upper_fence)

# Add the outlier points
fig <- fig %>%
  add_trace(
    data = filtered_df,
    x = ~factor(site_name),  
    y = ~value,  
    color = ~factor(site_type),
    colors = landuse_colors,
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers",
    marker = list(size = 5, opacity = 0.6),  # Customize marker appearance
    showlegend = FALSE,  # Hide legend for scatter points if desired
    inherit = FALSE
  )

# Show the figure
fig


You were so close! You need to call the argument scattermode = 'group' in the call for layout().
However, because the version of Plotly used by the R library by default is so old, it won't work without updating the Plotly.Js dependency that the R library relies on.
The points were a bit off center after updating, boxgap was used to align the markers. The value of 1/5 was used because there are 6 groups leading to 5 between-groups' space.

You can use arguments like boxgap and boxgroupgap to adjust the appearance, but I don't believe that scattergap or scattergroupgap were added to Plotly with addition of scattermode.

The code
I used a UDF to update the Plotly.Js dependency. (There are multiple arguments in the Plotly library that don't work in R without this update, so this function could be useful for a variety of reasons...)
fixer <- function(plt) {
       # changes to dependency so that all code works
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$file = NULL
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$src$href = "https://cdn.plot.ly"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$script = "plotly-2.33.0.min.js"
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$local = FALSE
  plt$dependencies[[5]]$package = NULL
  plt
}

The boxplot, markers, layout and the updated dependency

If you comment out, hide, or remove fixer(), you'll see that the call for scattermode is ignored.

plot_ly(data = stats_df, x = ~site_name, color = ~site_type,   # boxes
         colors = c("blue","red"), type = "box",
         lowerfence = ~lower_fence, q1 = ~q1, median = ~median,
         q3 = ~q3, upperfence = ~upper_fence) %>% 
    add_markers(data = filtered_df, x = ~site_name, y = ~value, # markers
                color = ~site_type, showlegend = F,
                marker = list(size = 5, opacity = 0.6)) %>% 
    layout(boxmode = "group", scattermode = "group", boxgap = 1/5) %>% # align
    fixer()                                   # update Plotly dependency

The boxplot with aligned outliers.


So close and yet so far! Thanks @Kat. Works like a charm. I would never have figured out that plotly version issue.

Also, in this solution I would keep the inherit=TRUE in the add_marker call to get rid of one of the warnings. Finally, do you also get a warning Warning message: 'layout' objects don't have these attributes: 'boxmode', 'scattermode', 'boxgap' Valid attributes include: '_deprecated', 'activeshape ...',? It doesn't seem to cause a problem but its messy and I can't get rid of it.

No, that warking isn't going anywhere, you could hide warnings, though. (I find it to be annoying, as well...and incorrect, obviously.)

OK, it isn't just me that can't get it to go away through conventional means. It seems like that incorrect warning has been documented for a long time as well. Ah well. Thanks again for the great solution.

I have been using this solution in a shiny app and unfortunately it won't render when I use the fixer() function. When I leave it out it renders, but the original problem persists. Is there any reason why you might expect this to happen?

Initially, I thought I recalled that yes, you needed to do something different. However, I just tested it and it ran in Shiny without changes. Where are you putting the call for fixer? When I tested it, I put the UDF outside of the ui and server. Do you get an error or is it just ignoring the update?

Thanks again Kat, I just found a solution to this. When using this in Shiny I had to specify plt$dependencies[[5]]$local = TRUE and then save the plotly js file in the www  folder and source with tags$script(src = "www/plotly-2.33.0.min.js"), in the app_ui.R file. Then it worked.  Not sure why Shiny can't get access it remotely. I had the fixer function after the layout call as per your example.

Hi @Kat ... I see you are really good with plotly ... I am having some troubles here, can you please recommend a solution if you are not too busy? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78909585/changing-the-color-of-text-in-plotly-based-on-background
