Changing the color of text in plotly based on background?
I have this plot in R (I wrote a function to select date labels to be spaced by 60 days to avoid clutter):
library(plotly)

n <- 100
mydf <- data.frame(
  col1 = rnorm(n),
  col2 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  col3 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10)
)

start_date <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2020-12-31")
mydf$point <- format(sample(seq(start_date, end_date, by="day"), n, replace = TRUE), "%Y-%m-%d")

mydf <- mydf[order(as.Date(mydf$point)), ]

filtered_dates <- mydf$point[1]
for (i in 2:nrow(mydf)) {
  if (as.Date(mydf$point[i]) >= as.Date(filtered_dates[length(filtered_dates)]) + 60) {
    filtered_dates <- c(filtered_dates, mydf$point[i])
  }
}
if (filtered_dates[length(filtered_dates)] != mydf$point[nrow(mydf)]) {
  filtered_dates <- c(filtered_dates, mydf$point[nrow(mydf)])
}

p <- plot_ly(data = mydf, x = ~col2, y = ~col3, z = ~col1, type = "contour")

x_min <- min(mydf$col2)
x_max <- max(mydf$col2)
y_min <- min(mydf$col3)
y_max <- max(mydf$col3)

for(i in 1:nrow(mydf)) {
  if (mydf$point[i] %in% filtered_dates) {
    x_pos <- max(min(mydf$col2[i], x_max), x_min)
    y_pos <- max(min(mydf$col3[i], y_max), y_min)
    
    label_x_pos <- jitter(x_pos, amount = 0.5)
    label_y_pos <- jitter(y_pos, amount = 0.5)
    
    p <- p %>% 
      add_annotations(x = label_x_pos, 
                      y = label_y_pos, 
                      text = paste0("• <b>", mydf$point[i], "</b>"), 
                      showarrow = FALSE,
                      font = list(size = 12, color = 'black'))
  }
}

p


I am trying to modify this plot so that the date labels around darker areas of the plot appear in white, and date labels around lighter areas of the plot appear in black (to improve visibility).
I tried looking for an automatic way to do this, but could not really find anything. I thought of the following idea:

For each label on the plot, identify the color of all pixels that surround this label (e.g. 5 pixels in each direction)
Take the average color of all those pixels: if the average is greater than some threshold "c" then black else white

But I am not sure how to access the underlying colors of the plotly plot. Can someone please show me how to do this?
Some ideas?

How to control label color depending on fill darkness of bars?
How can I make bar chart label colours conditional on the colour of the bar itself?
Contrast between label and background: determine if color is light or dark
ggplot2. How to change the color of data-labels depending on their background (geom_segment) ,
How to automatically change label color depending on relative values (maximum/minimum)?

Thanks!

The problem with taking the average pixel value or a similar methodology is that your label might be over an area with the lightest colour and the darkest colour. For instance, consider the top right label in your example plot.
To get around this issue, one possible option is to add a transparent background to your annotations using a combination of bgcolor, borderpad, and borderwidth.
In the example below, I have used an alpha value of 0.25 to minimise obscuring the plot 'real estate' under the labels. You can experiment with different background colours and alpha values to get an aesthetically balanced result.
library(plotly)

set.seed(42) # For reproducibility
n <- 100
mydf <- data.frame(
  col1 = rnorm(n),
  col2 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10),
  col3 = runif(n, min = 0, max = 10)
)

start_date <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2020-12-31")
mydf$point <- format(sample(seq(start_date, end_date, by="day"), n, replace = TRUE), "%Y-%m-%d")

mydf <- mydf[order(as.Date(mydf$point)), ]

filtered_dates <- mydf$point[1]
for (i in 2:nrow(mydf)) {
  if (as.Date(mydf$point[i]) >= as.Date(filtered_dates[length(filtered_dates)]) + 60) {
    filtered_dates <- c(filtered_dates, mydf$point[i])
  }
}
if (filtered_dates[length(filtered_dates)] != mydf$point[nrow(mydf)]) {
  filtered_dates <- c(filtered_dates, mydf$point[nrow(mydf)])
}

p <- plot_ly(data = mydf, x = ~col2, y = ~col3, z = ~col1, type = "contour")

x_min <- min(mydf$col2)
x_max <- max(mydf$col2)
y_min <- min(mydf$col3)
y_max <- max(mydf$col3)

for(i in 1:nrow(mydf)) {
  if (mydf$point[i] %in% filtered_dates) {
    x_pos <- max(min(mydf$col2[i], x_max), x_min)
    y_pos <- max(min(mydf$col3[i], y_max), y_min)
    
    label_x_pos <- jitter(x_pos, amount = 0.5)
    label_y_pos <- jitter(y_pos, amount = 0.5)
    
    p <- p %>% 
      add_annotations(x = label_x_pos, 
                      y = label_y_pos, 
                      text = paste0("• <b>", mydf$point[i], "</b>"), 
                      showarrow = FALSE,
                      font = list(size = 12, color = 'black'),
                      bgcolor = "rgba(255,255,255,0.25)",
                      borderpad = 0,
                      borderwidth = 0)
  }
}

p



@ L Tyrone: Thank you so much! btw - do you recommend anything to make the labels less crowded when there are many points on the plot?

@wulasa - I'd argue that constitutes a new question. You will need to consider what is the most important thing you want your plot to communicate and work from there. One option would be to use coloured points by month with a second legend and dispense with labels. Any solution should be data driven. For instance, how do the date points relate to your plot's story?

Well, it took a bit but I did work out a method that does what you were originally looking for. I see you have a great answer already, but I'm going to add it anyway.
This method uses the relative luminance (what's that?).

First it collects where the labels land in the svg drawn by plotly. (This changes depending on the graph size, browser, monitor size, all that jazz.)
Then it looks at each svg path to see if that label falls in that path. If it does fall in a particular path, the fill color is collected.
The collected colors are averaged by each area of their rgb. Then the luminance algorithm is used to see if they are closer to white or black, identifying the best suited label color.
additional code's been added to account for any label that extends outside of the plot - ensuring these labels are black

This requires the use the library htmlwidgets.
p %>% htmlwidgets::onRender(
  "function(el, x) {
    function recolor(el) {
      gcp = [], tat = [], sz = [];
      let lum = [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722];                         /* to compute luminance */
      lo = el.layout.annotations;                     /* get layout to update annotations */
                      /* get plot transform & svg size for validations */
      sz = document.querySelector('g.contourfill').getBoundingClientRect();
      
      let pnt = document.querySelector('svg').createSVGPoint();       /* create element to house label point checks */
                                                       /* to extract colors behind labels */
      let paths = document.querySelector('g.contourfill').childNodes;
      
                                                           /* get center pt of each annot */
      document.querySelectorAll('text.annotation-text').forEach((elm, ix) => {
          return tat[ix] = [elm.attributes.x.value, elm.attributes.y.value];
      })
                         /* get translate of each annot; then add values to x, y positions */
      document.querySelectorAll('g.cursor-pointer').forEach((elm, ix) => {
        x = elm.attributes.transform.value.replace(/[^\\d,]/g, '').split(',');
        gcp[ix] = [Number(x[0]) + Number(tat[ix][0]), Number(x[1]) + Number(tat[ix][1])/2 - 25];
      })   /* this is the list of points */
      
      gcp.forEach((elm, ix) => {     /* for each label annotated */
        let vals = [];                                      /* reset values every iteration*/
        pnt.x = elm[0]; pnt.y = elm[1];       /* add label point data to svg point element */
        for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {              /* for each svg path in plot */
          if(paths[i].isPointInFill(pnt)) {                         /* if label is in path */
              x = paths[i].style.fill;                         /* collect fill rgb if true */
              vals[i] = x.replace(/[^\\d,]/g, '').split(',');           /* extract numbers */
          } /* end if */
        }  /* end for */
        if(vals.length < 1) {vals[0] = [255,255,255];}/* catch if no in path matches found */
                                                      /* if any part is off of plot space? */
        tac =  document.querySelectorAll('text.annotation-text')[ix].getBoundingClientRect();
        if(tac.x < sz.x || tac.y < sz.y || tac.x + tac.width/2 > sz.width + 60 || tac.top + tac.height/2 > sz.height + 25) {
          vals = [];
          vals[0] = [255, 255, 255]; 
        }
                             /* convert rgb values to numbers, then average each (r, g, b) */
        let aveV = vals[0].map((
          col, i) => vals.map(row => row[i]).reduce((
            acc, c) => Number(acc) + Number(c), 0) / vals.length);
                                                /* use averages of r, g, b in to calc lums */
        let resClr = aveV.reduce(function(tot, v, ix) {return tot + (v * lum[ix])}, 0);
        let newClr = resClr > 100 ? 'black' : 'white';     /* id preferred color for label */
                                                          /* update fill color for element */
                                                   /* immediate gratification color change */
        document.querySelectorAll('text.annotation-text')[ix].style.fill = newClr;
        lo[ix].font.color = newClr;
      }) /* end forEach */
    }
    recolor(el);
    Plotly.relayout(el.id, annotations = {lo})
  }"
)

Here you can see that 2 labels are off the plot.

Here one label falls in the lighter green; one off plot

I've tried to add sufficient comments so you can follow what's happening. However, if you have any questions let me know.

Thank you so much Kat! I am about to post another question ... do you know much about jitter in plotly? e.g. i  have a lot of labels, is there a way to re-oganize the labels?

I don't know of an inherently Plotly method other than plot, adjust, plot, adjust...and so on. However, as it's built on HTML, there's probably something that can be done  a bit easier and that's better for dynamic sizing within JS using htmlwidgets.
